Given an $n$ such that for all $m \neq n$, then $\phi(n) \neq \phi(m)$, prove that $4 \mid n$
I got this question in my homework:

Given an $n$ such that for all $m \neq n$, then $\phi(n) \neq \phi(m)$, prove that $4 \mid n$.

Here's what I tried:
Assume by contradiction that $4 \nmid n$. Let's observe the case that $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$:
we can write $n=2k$ for some odd $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $k <n$.
Then, $\phi(n)=\phi(2k)=\phi(2) \cdot \phi(k)=\phi(k)$. If we choose $k=m$, that's a contradiction to $\phi(n) \neq \phi(m)$.
Now I'm stuck on the case where $2 \nmid n$, I don't know what to do.

@MartinBrandenburg the question in the title, given an $n$ such that for all $m \neq n$, then $\phi(n) \neq \phi(m)$, prove that $4 \mid n$

Note that for odd $n$ you can basically reuse what you did with $\phi(n)=\phi(2k)$, but with different values.

oh my god I get it

Excellent! I couldn't find a duplicate with an Approach0 search so, although I suspect a duplicate likely exists somewhere here, you may wish to write and post your own answer. Alternatively, if you're concerned about this, perhaps you may want to just delete your question instead.

I won't delete my question in case someone faces a similar problem. If that person is still having problems, consider $\phi(2n)$

Yes, that's the remainder of your solution. Please consider posting an answer so that it can be upvoted and/or accepted, in which case this question will then be considered by the SE system to be "answered" and, thus, taken off the "unanswered" list.

I've written an answer : can't find a duplicate, and this is a good question.

Answering for completion :
If $n$ is not a multiple of $4$, then $n$ is either odd or an odd multiple of $2$.
If $n=2k$ with $k$ odd then $\phi(n) = \phi(2k) = \phi(2)\phi(k) = \phi(k)$.
If $n$ is odd then $\phi(2n) = \phi(2)\phi(n) = \phi(n)$.
In either case, a there is a number $K$ different from $n$ such that $\phi(K) = \phi(n)$. The contrapositive is that a number which admits no such $K$ is a multiple of $4$.

In fact, you might want to check out Carmichael's conjecture. It states that for any positive integer $n$, there is a different positive integer $m$ such that $\phi(n) = \phi(m)$. We showed this to be true when $n$ is not a multiple of $4$ : but the general question is still open. See here for more details.
